# How to schedule an automatic TFS release deployment?

Tags: tfs

we have established a database size monitor release definition and would like to have it run/deploy every sunday at 11pm automatically.

I am checking out the artifacts schedule part

[image: arti]

Is this how its done? Or does this create Only releases? Because we want them to get deployed automatically too of course, but as you can see highlighted below, it says creates a new release…doesn’t say deployment…

[image: schedule]

is there another way to make it deploy without having to create a release every time? so basically create one release and use that forever unless changes are made to the defintion. otherwise, there'll be a TON of release which wont be ideal...

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT hi patrick, its definitely helpful! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not such a kind of schedule deployment based on a single same release.  However, you could set release pipeline like this:

1. On the pipeline / artifacts, remove your schedule as you did.

[image: arti]

2. Then **on your environment**, change the trigger to be **after
   release** and enable the schedule, choosing when you want it to
   start.

[image]

Also in your environment change the deployment queue settings to "**deploy latest and cancel others**".

3. Click on your artifact and enable the CD trigger.

As you can see under Triggers, `define the trigger that will start deployment to this environment`.  When a CI build completed, it will start a release, then it will wait the schedule defined time and try to deploy to your environment set.

Once you build again, the previous release will be canceled to replace the new one. You maybe have more releases, but you won't deploy if there were no changes.

Hope this helps.